# Is there a way to Change Class variable from inner Method

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a ListView below with an ArrayAdapter to make a simple List view with corresponding Html elements added to *assets* folder.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity

{


String indx;

    String[] values = { "index", "Prooo", "My Android Examples","My Android Tutorials","My Android Pages", "My Android Favorites"};



    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        // parameters are (Context, layout for the row, and the array of data)

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

                                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));

    }

    
    @Override

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)

    {
        indx = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this,indx,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    
    
    



}
```

Everything else works fine but the aim is to change the String **indx** value with the item  **Position** returned by **onListItemClick** as each Html document's name is the same as that of each String **values** item.

I tired to access **indx** from a class WebViewActivity to display the Html but the String **indx** value is still **Null**.

> I would've specify something like **Public indx** if it was Python please is there any way to change **Indx** like that in Java and I can't use **return** because **void** cannot return

Comment: "with the item Position returned by onListItemClick", that method doesn't return anything? It is unclear to me what the problem is. Could you be more specific about what you are trying to do and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: indx = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);          returns a string. ** Or am I missing something? **                  I was able to use the resulting String to make A toast message.                    ```Toast.makeText(this,indx,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();```

Comment: I still do not understand where you need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Accessing indx in WebViewActivity. You need to pass the value through intent like below,

```
 Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("index",indx);      
startActivity(i);
```

For getting your string in WebViewActivity use below code in WebViewActivity,
add below code in Oncreate of WebViewActivity

```
String index=getIntent().getStringExtra("index");
```

Comment: Ok, below is WebViewActivity.java code. After doing that, it throws NullPointerException.                   ```public class WebViewActivity extends Activity
{
 String index=getIntent().getStringExtra("index");
 MainActivity a=new MainActivity();
 WebView webView;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.webview);
  webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webhview);
   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+index+".html");
   
  
 }
 
}```    Please help look into this

Comment: @Mab u need to add this ```String index=getIntent().getStringExtra("index");``` into ur OnCreate of WebView Activity

Comment: **Not solved yet. The log cat below**: ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
06-20 15:02:28.393 6708 6708```

Comment: @Mab you added ```i.putExtra("index",indx);  ``` this code before startIntent. Right?

Comment: I have no idea of the putExtra before now, if you could help with any blog/documentation about it or even java/xml in general.    *Anyway* **Thanks alot**. Made my day

Comment: @Mab  superb :-) refer this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters  it may help you..